# interaction.member.fetch(); Triggers on other interaction commands

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Hi my problem is if any user trigger a command or a button (a interaction), then it triggers this line: "await member.send('**Du bist bereits auf YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY verifiziert!**');" in Code 1.

Example: A user trigger the button in Code 2, he get the DM message from the bot from code 1.

What makes code 1?

It's a verification system, you press the button choose in a select menu that you accept the rules then it open a Modal where you enter you server nickname, then you select in a other select menu a ping role.
You get the nickname the choosed role and the member role from the bot.

But if you already a member this line in code 1 triggers and send you the DM "if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has('707275842295955530')) {".

But for some reason the bot sends the DM even when other interactions are triggered.

Code 1:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Command = require('../../structures/CommandClass');
const { stripIndents } = require('common-tags');
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, TextInputStyle, StringSelectMenuBuilder, Events, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder } = require('discord.js');

let ninputvalues = {};
    
module.exports = class verifiy extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
                .setName('sendverifizierung')
                .setDescription('Sende das Verifizierungs Embed')
                .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers)
                .setDMPermission(false),          
        });
    }
        
      
  async run(client, interaction) {
    let member = await interaction.member.fetch();
    const verifiychannelID = '1052951990331773019';
    const verifiychannel =  member.guild.channels.cache.get(verifiychannelID);
    const glocke = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('884820297977573386');
    const news = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('1032524990274351134');
    const memberrole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('707275842295955530');
    
    let failsafe = false;
  
    

      const rulesmenü = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('rulesmenü')
                    .setPlaceholder('Antwort auswählen')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: 'Ja, gelesen und einverstanden.',                           
                            value: 'ja',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Nein, nicht gelsesen und nicht einverstanden.',                           
                            value: 'nein',
                        },
                    ),
            );
            const rolemenü = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('rolemenü')
                    .setPlaceholder('Rolle auswählen')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: 'YU91 Glocke',
                            description: 'Erhalte extra Benachrichtigungen über Yankeeunit91.',                          
                            value: 'glocke',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Gaming News',
                            description: 'Erhalte extra Benachrichtigungen für Neue Infos über z.B Spiele etc.',                          
                            value: 'news',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Keine',
                            description: 'Erhalte keine Rolle.',                        
                            value: 'keine',
                        },
            
                    ),
            );


      
      const modalsv = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('ninput')
            .setTitle('YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY');


      const nameinput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('nameinput') 
            .setLabel("Server Nickname")
      .setPlaceholder('Keine Sonderzeichen!')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
      .setMinLength(2)
      .setMaxLength(32)
      .setRequired(true);


    
      
      const firstActionRowv = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(nameinput);
     
      modalsv.addComponents(firstActionRowv);

      
      
   
  
  const verifeembed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle(`Verifizieren dich!`)
  .setColor('#00ff0c')
  .setDescription(stripIndents`Durch das verifizieren erhälst du zugriff auf die YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY!`)
  .setFooter({ text: 'YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY'})
  .setTimestamp();
  
 
  
  
     
  const buttonva = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('buttonanfrageverify')
          .setEmoji('✅')
                    .setLabel('Verifizieren')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),
            );
            
           
            client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
              const member = await interaction.member.fetch();
                    if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has('707275842295955530')) {
                      await member.send('**Du bist bereits auf YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY verifiziert!**');
                      return interaction.deferUpdate()
                    
                  } else if (interaction.isButton()) {
                    const buttonID = interaction.customId
                    if (buttonID === 'buttonanfrageverify') {
                      await interaction.reply({ content:'**Hast du die Regeln gelesen, und bist du damit einverstanden?**', components: [rulesmenü], ephemeral: true });
                      
                    }
                }
              
              
          
        });      
      
      

    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
      if (interaction.isStringSelectMenu()) {
          
          const selected = interaction.values.join(', ');
          if (selected === 'ja') {
            await interaction.showModal(modalsv);
          } else if (selected === 'nein') {
            await interaction.update({ content:'**Lese dir die Regeln erneut durch! Solltest du nicht mit denn Regeln einverstanden sein, bitten wir dich denn Server zu verlassen.**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
          }
      }
  });
    
    
  verifiychannel.send({ embeds: [verifeembed], components: [buttonva] });
  await interaction.reply({ content: 'Verifizierungs Embed wurde versendet!', ephemeral: true });
  
  
  
  client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        if (interaction.customId === "ninput") {
            await interaction.update({ content:'**Wähle eine Role für die du dich interresierst!**', components: [rolemenü], ephemeral: true });
            var ninputdata = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('nameinput');
            ninputvalues[interaction.user.id] = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('nameinput');
            ninputvalues[interaction.user.id] = ninputvalues[interaction.user.id].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, 'X');
         
          }
        } else if (interaction.isStringSelectMenu()) {
          const selected = interaction.values[0];
          const member = await interaction.member.fetch();
          
          if (selected === 'glocke') {
            await interaction.update({ content:'**Du hast die \`YU91 Glocke\` erhalten. Willkommen in der YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY!**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
            await member.roles.add(glocke)
            await interaction.member.setNickname(`${ninputvalues[interaction.user.id]}`).catch(e => (failsafe = true));
            return await member.roles.add(memberrole);
          } else if (selected === 'news') {
            await interaction.update({ content:'**Du hast die \`Gaming News\` erhalten. Willkommen in der YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY!**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
            await member.roles.add(news)
            await interaction.member.setNickname(`${ninputvalues[interaction.user.id]}`).catch(e => (failsafe = true));
            return await member.roles.add(memberrole);
          } else if (selected === 'keine') {
            await interaction.update({ content:'**Willkommen in der YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY!**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
            await interaction.member.setNickname(`${ninputvalues[interaction.user.id]}`).catch(e => (failsafe = true));
            await member.roles.add(memberrole);
          } 
                
          
          };
        });
        
  
        
   

}


};
```

Code 2

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Command = require('../../structures/CommandClass');
const { stripIndents } = require('common-tags');
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, TextInputStyle, StringSelectMenuBuilder, Events, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder } = require('discord.js');

let sinputvalues = {};
let ginputvalues = {};
let pfmenüvalues = {};
    
module.exports = class spielersuche extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
                .setName('sendspielersuche')
                .setDescription('Sende das Spielersuche Embed')
                .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers)
                .setDMPermission(false),          
        });
    }
        
      
  async run(client, interaction) {
    let member = await interaction.member.fetch();
    const anfragechannelID = '889302458906591344';
    const anfragechannel =  member.guild.channels.cache.get(anfragechannelID);
    const createanfragechannelID = '1052951990331773019';
    const createanfragechannel =  member.guild.channels.cache.get(createanfragechannelID);
   
  
    

      const pfmenü = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('pfmenü')
                    .setPlaceholder('Plattform auswählen (Scrollen)')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: 'PS4',                           
                            value: 'PS4',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'PS5',                           
                            value: 'PS5',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'PS4/PS5',                           
                            value: 'PS4/PS5',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'PC',                        
                            value: 'PC',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Switch',                            
                            value: 'Switch',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Xbox One',      
                            value: 'Xbox One',
                        },
            {
                          label: 'Xbox Series',                        
                          value: 'Xbox Series',
                        },
              {
                          label: 'Xbox One/Xbox Series',                        
                          value: 'Xbox One/Xbox Series',
                        },
            {
                          label: 'Alle',                        
                          value: 'Alle',
                      },
                    ),
            );
            const spmenü = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('spmenü')
                    .setPlaceholder('Mitspieleranzahl auswählen (Scrollen)')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: '1',                           
                            value: '1 Mitspieler',
                        },
            {
                            label: '2',                           
                            value: '2 Mitspieler',
                        },
            {
                            label: '3',                           
                            value: '3 Mitspieler',
                        },
            {
                            label: '4',                        
                            value: '4 Mitspieler',
                        },
            {
                            label: '5',                            
                            value: '5 Mitspieler',
                        },
            {
                            label: '6',      
                            value: '6 Mitspieler',
                        },
            {
                          label: '7',                        
                          value: '7 Mitspieler',
                        },
              {
                          label: '8',                        
                          value: '8 Mitspieler',
                        },
            {
                          label: '9+',                        
                          value: '9+ Mitspieler',
                      },
                    ),
            );


      
      const modals = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('minput')
            .setTitle('Spielersuche ');


      const spielinput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('spielinput') 
            .setLabel("Für welches Spiel?")
      .setPlaceholder('GTA5, Fortnite, Call of Duty, Minecraft ...')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
      .setMinLength(2)
      .setMaxLength(20)
      .setRequired(true);

      const grundinput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('grundinput')         
            .setLabel("Der Grund der Anfrage?")   
      .setPlaceholder('Beispiel: Suche Spieler für Cayo Perico Heist.') 
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
      .setMinLength(10)
      .setMaxLength(60)
      .setRequired(true);

    
      
      const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(spielinput);
      const secondActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(grundinput);
      modals.addComponents(firstActionRow, secondActionRow);

      
      
   
  
  const spielersucheerweitertEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle(`Spieler suchen Spieler `)
  .setColor('#00ff0c')
  .setDescription(stripIndents`Drücke auf denn Button um eine Spielersuche Anzufragen!`)
  .setFooter({ text: 'YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY'})
  .setTimestamp();
  
 
  
 
     
  const buttonsa = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('buttonanfrage')
          .setEmoji('')
                    .setLabel('Spielersuche Anfragen')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),
            );
      
      
      client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        if (interaction.isButton()) {
            const buttonID = interaction.customId
            if (buttonID === 'buttonanfrage') {
              await interaction.showModal(modals);
            }
        }
    });
    
    
  createanfragechannel.send({ embeds: [spielersucheerweitertEmbed], components: [buttonsa] });
  await interaction.reply({ content: 'Spielersuche Embed wurde versendet!', ephemeral: true });

  client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        if (interaction.customId === "minput") {
            await interaction.reply({ content:'**Wähle deine Plattform!**', components: [pfmenü], ephemeral: true });
            var ginputdata = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('grundinput');
            ginputvalues[interaction.user.id] = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('grundinput');
            var sinputdata = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('spielinput');
            sinputvalues[interaction.user.id] = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('spielinput');
         
          }
        } else if (interaction.isStringSelectMenu()) {
            if (interaction.customId === "pfmenü") {
              await interaction.update({ content:'**Wähle wie viele Mitpsieler gesucht werden!**', components: [spmenü], ephemeral: true });
              var pfmenüdata = interaction.values.join(', ');
              pfmenüvalues[interaction.user.id] = interaction.values.join(', ');
        
            }
          const spanzahl = await interaction.values.join(', ');
          
          const spielersucheerweitertEmbedfertig = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setTitle(`${ginputvalues[interaction.user.id]}`)
          .setColor('#00ff0c')
          .setFooter({ text: 'YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY'})
          .setTimestamp()
          .addFields(
            {
              name: '**Spiel:**',
              value: `${sinputvalues[interaction.user.id]}`,
              inline: true,
            },
            {
              name: `**Plattform:**`,
              value: `${pfmenüvalues[interaction.user.id]}`,
              inline: false,
            },
            {
              name: `**Mitspieleranzahl gesucht:**`,
              value: `${spanzahl}`,
              inline: false,
            },
          );
         
          if (interaction.customId === "spmenü") {
            const member = await interaction.member.fetch();
            await interaction.update({ content:'**Spielersuche erfolgreich Angefragt!**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
            return await anfragechannel.send({  content: `**Anfrage von:** <@${member.id}>`, embeds: [spielersucheerweitertEmbedfertig] });
          }
                
          
          };
        });
        
  
        
   

}


};
```

I didnt know why it is but i think form this line: "const member = await interaction.member.fetch();" in code 1, but i dont know how to fix that.

Comment: (OT) 1. There is no reason to force-fetch a member. Which you do by doing `const member = await interaction.member.fetch();`. You can simply use `interaction.member`. 2. Are you sure the member doesn't have the `<@707275842295955530> ` role? 3. There is no reason to have five `interactionCreate` events. Use one for simplicity, better performance and overall more readable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Thanks @Tetie i Fixed it. I write all interactionCreate Events to one interactionCreate Event, replaced the `const member = await interaction.member.fetch();` with `interaction.member.`

And i changed some on the syntax.

Code Befor:

```
const Command = require('../../structures/CommandClass');
const { stripIndents } = require('common-tags');
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, TextInputStyle, StringSelectMenuBuilder, Events, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder } = require('discord.js');

let ninputvalues = {};
    
module.exports = class verifiy extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
                .setName('sendverifizierung')
                .setDescription('Sende das Verifizierungs Embed')
                .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers)
                .setDMPermission(false),          
        });
    }
        
      
  async run(client, interaction) {
    let member = await interaction.member.fetch();
    const verifiychannelID = '1052951990331773019';
    const verifiychannel =  member.guild.channels.cache.get(verifiychannelID);
    const glocke = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('884820297977573386');
    const news = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('1032524990274351134');
    const memberrole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('707275842295955530');
    
    let failsafe = false;
  
    

      const rulesmenü = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('rulesmenü')
                    .setPlaceholder('Antwort auswählen')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: 'Ja, gelesen und einverstanden.',                           
                            value: 'ja',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Nein, nicht gelsesen und nicht einverstanden.',                           
                            value: 'nein',
                        },
                    ),
            );
            const rolemenü = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('rolemenü')
                    .setPlaceholder('Rolle auswählen')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: 'YU91 Glocke',
                            description: 'Erhalte extra Benachrichtigungen über Yankeeunit91.',                          
                            value: 'glocke',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Gaming News',
                            description: 'Erhalte extra Benachrichtigungen für Neue Infos über z.B Spiele etc.',                          
                            value: 'news',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Keine',
                            description: 'Erhalte keine Rolle.',                        
                            value: 'keine',
                        },
            
                    ),
            );


      
      const modalsv = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('ninput')
            .setTitle('YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY');


      const nameinput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('nameinput') 
            .setLabel("Server Nickname")
      .setPlaceholder('Keine Sonderzeichen!')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
      .setMinLength(2)
      .setMaxLength(32)
      .setRequired(true);


    
      
      const firstActionRowv = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(nameinput);
     
      modalsv.addComponents(firstActionRowv);

      
      
   
  
  const verifeembed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle(`Verifizieren dich!`)
  .setColor('#00ff0c')
  .setDescription(stripIndents`Durch das verifizieren erhälst du zugriff auf die YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY!`)
  .setFooter({ text: 'YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY'})
  .setTimestamp();
  
 
  
  
     
  const buttonva = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('buttonanfrageverify')
          .setEmoji('✅')
                    .setLabel('Verifizieren')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),
            );
            
           
            client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
              const member = await interaction.member.fetch();
                    if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has('707275842295955530')) {
                      await member.send('**Du bist bereits auf YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY verifiziert!**');
                      return interaction.deferUpdate()
                    
                  } else if (interaction.isButton()) {
                    const buttonID = interaction.customId
                    if (buttonID === 'buttonanfrageverify') {
                      await interaction.reply({ content:'**Hast du die Regeln gelesen, und bist du damit einverstanden?**', components: [rulesmenü], ephemeral: true });
                      
                    }
                }
              
              
          
        });      
      
      

    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
      if (interaction.isStringSelectMenu()) {
          
          const selected = interaction.values.join(', ');
          if (selected === 'ja') {
            await interaction.showModal(modalsv);
          } else if (selected === 'nein') {
            await interaction.update({ content:'**Lese dir die Regeln erneut durch! Solltest du nicht mit denn Regeln einverstanden sein, bitten wir dich denn Server zu verlassen.**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
          }
      }
  });
    
    
  verifiychannel.send({ embeds: [verifeembed], components: [buttonva] });
  await interaction.reply({ content: 'Verifizierungs Embed wurde versendet!', ephemeral: true });
  
  
  
  client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        if (interaction.customId === "ninput") {
            await interaction.update({ content:'**Wähle eine Role für die du dich interresierst!**', components: [rolemenü], ephemeral: true });
            var ninputdata = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('nameinput');
            ninputvalues[interaction.user.id] = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('nameinput');
            ninputvalues[interaction.user.id] = ninputvalues[interaction.user.id].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, 'X');
         
          }
        } else if (interaction.isStringSelectMenu()) {
          const selected = interaction.values[0];
          const member = await interaction.member.fetch();
          
          if (selected === 'glocke') {
            await interaction.update({ content:'**Du hast die \`YU91 Glocke\` erhalten. Willkommen in der YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY!**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
            await member.roles.add(glocke)
            await interaction.member.setNickname(`${ninputvalues[interaction.user.id]}`).catch(e => (failsafe = true));
            return await member.roles.add(memberrole);
          } else if (selected === 'news') {
            await interaction.update({ content:'**Du hast die \`Gaming News\` erhalten. Willkommen in der YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY!**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
            await member.roles.add(news)
            await interaction.member.setNickname(`${ninputvalues[interaction.user.id]}`).catch(e => (failsafe = true));
            return await member.roles.add(memberrole);
          } else if (selected === 'keine') {
            await interaction.update({ content:'**Willkommen in der YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY!**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
            await interaction.member.setNickname(`${ninputvalues[interaction.user.id]}`).catch(e => (failsafe = true));
            await member.roles.add(memberrole);
          } 
                
          
          };
        });
        
  
        
   

}


};
```

After:

````
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Command = require('../../structures/CommandClass');
const { stripIndents } = require('common-tags');
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, TextInputStyle, StringSelectMenuBuilder, Events, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder } = require('discord.js');

let ninputvalues = {};
    
module.exports = class verifiy extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
                .setName('sendverifizierung')
                .setDescription('Sende das Verifizierungs Embed')
                .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers)
                .setDMPermission(false),          
        });
    }
        
      
  async run(client, interaction) {
    
    const verifiychannelID = '644218169422250014';
    const verifiychannel =  interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(verifiychannelID);
    const glocke = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('884820297977573386');
    const news = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('1032524990274351134');
    const memberrole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('707275842295955530');
    let failsafe = false;
   
  
    

      const rulesmenü = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('rulesmenü')
                    .setPlaceholder('Antwort auswählen')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: 'Ja, gelesen und einverstanden.',                           
                            value: 'ja',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Nein, nicht gelsesen und nicht einverstanden.',                           
                            value: 'nein',
                        },
                    ),
            );
            const rolemenü = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('rolemenü')
                    .setPlaceholder('Rolle auswählen')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: 'YU91 Glocke',
                            description: 'Erhalte extra Benachrichtigungen über Yankeeunit91.',                          
                            value: 'glocke',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Gaming News',
                            description: 'Erhalte extra Benachrichtigungen für Neue Infos über z.B Spiele etc.',                          
                            value: 'news',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Keine',
                            description: 'Erhalte keine Rolle.',                        
                            value: 'keine',
                        },
            
                    ),
            );


      
      const modalsv = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('ninput')
            .setTitle('YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY');


      const nameinput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('nameinput') 
            .setLabel("Server Nickname")
      .setPlaceholder('Keine Sonderzeichen!')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
      .setMinLength(2)
      .setMaxLength(32)
      .setRequired(true);


    
      
      const firstActionRowv = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(nameinput);
     
      modalsv.addComponents(firstActionRowv);

      
      
   
  
  const verifeembed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle(`Verifizieren dich!`)
  .setColor('#00ff0c')
  .setDescription(stripIndents`Durch das verifizieren erhälst du zugriff auf die YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY!`)
  .setFooter({ text: 'YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY'})
  .setTimestamp();
  
 
  
  
     
  const buttonva = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('buttonanfrageverify')
          .setEmoji('✅')
                    .setLabel('Verifizieren')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),
            );
            
            
            client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
             
                  if (interaction.isButton()) {
                    const buttonID = interaction.customId
                    if (buttonID === 'buttonanfrageverify') {
                      if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has('707275842295955530')) {
                        await interaction.reply({ content: '**Du bist bereits auf YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY verifiziert!**',  ephemeral: true });
                      }
                       else await interaction.reply({ content:'**Hast du die Regeln gelesen, und bist du damit einverstanden?**', components: [rulesmenü], ephemeral: true });
                    }                                         
                  } else if (interaction.isStringSelectMenu()) {
                    const selected = interaction.values.join(', ');
                    if (selected === 'ja') {
                      await interaction.showModal(modalsv);
                    } else if (selected === 'nein') {
                      await interaction.update({ content:'**Lese dir die Regeln erneut durch! Solltest du nicht mit denn Regeln einverstanden sein, bitten wir dich denn Server zu verlassen.**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
                    }
                  } if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
                    if (interaction.customId === "ninput") {
                        await interaction.update({ content:'**Wähle eine Role für die du dich interresierst!**', components: [rolemenü], ephemeral: true });
                        var ninputdata = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('nameinput');
                        ninputvalues[interaction.user.id] = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('nameinput');
                        ninputvalues[interaction.user.id] = ninputvalues[interaction.user.id].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, 'X');
                     
                      }
                    } else if (interaction.isStringSelectMenu()) {
                      const selected = interaction.values[0];
                      
                      
                      if (selected === 'glocke') {
                        await interaction.update({ content:'**Du hast die \`YU91 Glocke\` erhalten. Willkommen in der YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY!**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
                        await interaction.member.roles.add(glocke)
                        await interaction.member.setNickname(`${ninputvalues[interaction.user.id]}`).catch(e => (failsafe = true));
                        return await interaction.member.roles.add(memberrole);
                      } else if (selected === 'news') {
                        await interaction.update({ content:'**Du hast die \`Gaming News\` erhalten. Willkommen in der YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY!**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
                        await interaction.member.roles.add(news)
                        await interaction.member.setNickname(`${ninputvalues[interaction.user.id]}`).catch(e => (failsafe = true));
                        return await interaction.member.roles.add(memberrole);
                      } else if (selected === 'keine') {
                        await interaction.update({ content:'**Willkommen in der YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY!**', components: [], ephemeral: true });
                        await interaction.member.setNickname(`${ninputvalues[interaction.user.id]}`).catch(e => (failsafe = true));
                        await interaction.member.roles.add(memberrole);
                      } 
                            
                      
                      };
              
              
          
        });      
    
  verifiychannel.send({ embeds: [verifeembed], components: [buttonva] });
  await interaction.reply({ content: 'Verifizierungs Embed wurde versendet!', ephemeral: true });

}


};```
````